# Tic Tac Toe array

Tags: c#, arrays

In C#, I have a tic tac toe game in which I have a method to check the outcome of if the player won, lost, or it was a tie. I'm having a problem with the code checking if it's a tie. So right now I have this. And I want it so if there is a space in any of the elements the game is not a draw and continues on. When I run the code it would randomly say its a tie even when the game isn't finished yet.

```
        bool draw = true;
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                if (matrix[row, col] == ' ')
                {
                    bool draw = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (draw)
        {
            return 'D'; //return D for draw
        }
```

Comment: post a complete solution so we can understand the code, from what you've posted it's hard to guess.

Comment: This sounds like it should be pretty easy to debug. Put a break on the return 'D' and check the values in your matrix when it hits it. That should tell you what is going wrong...

Answer (score 2):

You aren't setting the variable draw, but declaring a new variable in the inner scope.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code is as @RandRandom said, you're declaring a new variable in your inner loop, instead of changing your declared `draw` variable. One other performance point about your code is you'd better to use `break` when your condition becomes true to have a better performance. One other point is that you'd better use `Enums` instead of returning `string` or `char` in such situations to prevent any mistyping errors.

```
        enum DrawResult
        {
            Draw,
            NotDraw
        }

        bool draw = true;
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                if (char.IsWhiteSpace(matrix[row, col]))
                {
                    draw = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (draw)
        {
            return DrawResult.Draw; //return D for draw
        }
        return DrawResult.NotDraw
```

Answer (score 0):

To expound on another answer, the problem is that when you come to the line "bool draw = false;" you are not in the same scope as when you originally declared the variable.  Because you are inside a for loop, you are allowed to reuse variable names and you are incorrectly declaring a new variable because you put 'bool' in front of it.  When you leave the scope of the loop, this new variable is automatically destroyed by the garbage collector.  The only fix you need to make is remove "bool" from the front of this line.